# Responsive response not right in chart drawing

Tags: responsive-design, vuetify.js, chartist.js

I have a created a simple line chart with the [Chartist](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js) library but I'm having it display properly. Interestingly the SVG element is correctly taking 100% of the width AND the CSS class imposes the right aspect ratio (aka, height) as well. Other than that, however, the drawing itself is all jammed into the wrong space.

[image]

To see what it *should* look like:

[image]

I've created a GIST with the JS code along with the SVG: [gist.](https://gist.github.com/ksnyde/568b43e5b6d3dbd4fc27470fe7eadfb8?short_path=56200fc)

What is undoubtedly complicating things is that I'm working within the popular **Vuetify** UI framework and specifically within the [Expansion Panels](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels) component which toggles blocks in and out of view using `display: none`.

What I'm hoping for is a way to get this just to respond correctly, however, if I must however, I am open to force the browser to re-eval the page (or just this section). I'm really not sure what in the SVG/CSS/Browser sizing is causing the overall effect but in an attempt to reach out to the manual re-eval I did try adding the following code:

```
public mounted() {
  this.$el.getBoundingClientRect(); // (1) trying to force browser to re-eval
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.chart(); // (2) waiting for render before adding the chart
  });
}
```

Unfortunately these desperate tweeks didn't work.

Comment: I have created a short video of me interacting with the UI. In this you can also see that once a given Panel has been resized to show the chart it can be hidden and re-exposed but each Panel needs to be individually resized to show: https://www.screencast.com/t/qhVEjXLC